# jquery sum Price and Total Price of items

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, shopping-cart

Look at: http://jsfiddle.net/MLsAu/14/
in Asp.Net page_load , program calculate sum Price and Total Price and Sum Discount .but i want to calculate with jquery when user change one of dropdownlist values (quantity of products) . i know some of codes is wrong but i don't know where is wrong . for example , when user change first item quantity from 2 to 1 , SumPrice is wrong  !

i tested this code , but it's not ok.

```
               var sumPrice = 0;
               $('tr').each(function () {
                   sumPrice += parseInt(quantity * parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('.ffour').text()));
               });
               $('#txtSumPrice').html(sumPrice);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the sum total, discount and price to 0 within your change event each time, else it would take the last available value. Please find the corrected fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv5RS/2/).

```
$('.drop').on('change',function () {
    $('#txtSumDiscount').text('0');
    $('#txtSumPrice').text('0');
    $('#txtTotal').text('0');
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var price = $(tr).find('.ffour').html() - $(tr).find('.fthree').html();
    $(tr).find('.fone').html(price * $(this).val());

    var sum = 0, discount = 0, total =0;

    $(this).closest('#dvCart').find('tr td.fone').each(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var q = parseFloat($(parent).find('select.drop').val());
        sum += parseFloat($(parent).find('td.ffour').text()) * q;
        discount += parseFloat($(parent).find('td.fthree').text()) * q;
    });

    $('#txtSumPrice').html(sum);
    $('#txtSumDiscount').html(discount);
    $('#txtTotal').html(sum - discount);
});
```

Comment: txtSumPrice is Sum of All Items Price, but in your code, txtSumPrice show one item price .

Comment: in asp.net code-behind  , calculate sum of Prices and Discounts for page-load. but i want to change txtSumPrice when user change quantity value of one item .

Comment: can i send to you private message for other questions? i have written asp.net soloution for shopping cart like www.digikala.com

Comment: go to http://www.digikala.com/Product/DKP-21104/Lenovo-IdeaTab-A3000-16GB/%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%AA-%D9%84%D9%86%D9%88%D9%88-%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%AA%D8%A8-A3000-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-16-%DA%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA

Comment: i writed my soloution like this site.

Comment: click on add to cart button.in cart web page with your help i writed all codes . but i don't know this site how to goes to next step .

Comment: what meaning href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions ... ?

Comment: Kindly go through http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/__doPostBack-function to understand using _doPostBack

Comment: in your jsfiddle sample , how to transfer html contents like fone and ffour for each item to sql server database?

Comment: in this page html contents load from my website cookie (SiteCookie) .

Comment: my cookie has Qty field for maintain quantity of each item . how to change Qty in SiteCookie when user change quantity dropdownlist ?